# Pages not working in IE10 after deploying to server

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-10

When I run my project in IE10 in my local, it works fine. But when I deployed it on the server, my pages are not displaying as it should be and it is not working properly especially those parts with javascript. Can anybody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably the brower displays them with the engine of an older IE.
Try adding this in the head of your html/asp files:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I already have that in the head of my aspx file.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It could be that there's missing css or javascript. Any missing resource will show up in red.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any browser detection in .NET (i.e. HttpBrowserCapabilities)?  If so, it may be due to a bug where IE 10 is being seen as IE 1.  Try applying the hotfix for the version of .NET you are using from [this page](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and adding the below line solved the problem

**<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />**